# Why doesn't Server.HtmlDecode decodes data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, decode

I have used an Html TextArea tag to get html encoded data from database.

but it displays data in raw form i.e. with tags etc.

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">
               test body
             </label>
             <textarea><%= Server.HtmlDecode(bodytext) %></textarea>
         </div>
 </div>
```

why ?

Body text is a string i have used on server side.

Answer (score 0):

The `TEXTAREA` tag cannot display rendered HTML.
You need a special component to do that, google 'html web editor wysiwyg'.

Comment: i did. just simply sending html not decoding

Answer (score 0):

@Cuckoo you can use "HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)" like following

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">
               test body
             </label>
             <%= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(bodytext) %>
         </div>
 </div>
```